# Laravel: Check if session exists necessary?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Before I was using Laravel I did the following:

```
<input type="text" name="comment" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['comment'])) echo $_SESSION['comment']; ?>">
```

I had to check if `$_SESSION['comment']` exists in order to prevent a warning. Now inside my blade files I can translate this to

```
<input type="text" name="comment" value="{{ (isset(session('comment')) ? session('comment') : ''}}">
```

But I wonder if it is still necessary to check if the session exists or if I can simply write

```
<input type="text" name="comment" value="{{ session('comment') }}">
```

I could not find that in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#retrieving-data). I was looking in the [API](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/search.html?search=session) but I realized that I have no clue in which class I may find the global helper function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not check if the session is started. It starts automatically for you in Laravel.

If you try to display a `session(variable)` which does not exist, you will get `null`.

But if you'd rather have a default value, you pass it as the second parameter:

```
var_dump(session('Lorem ipsum4', 'default value'));
// will result in: 
// "default value"
```

All the `magic` **helper** methods in laravel are placed in a file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`. There you will find `function session` definition, somewhat as follows:

```
function session($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return app('session');
    }

    if (is_array($key)) {
        return app('session')->put($key);
    }

    return app('session')->get($key, $default);
}
```